# Unable to open xls (SpreadsheetML, XML Spreadsheet 2003, or XMLSS) on LibreOffice v5.4.4.2

Tags: xls, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, spreadsheetml

I have does the installation of LibreOffice Version: 5.4.4.2 (x64) Build ID: 2524958677847fb3bb44820e40380acbe820f960 on my organization and they can open all documents except one, a .xls file (SpreadsheetML, XML Spreadsheet 2003, or XMLSS) with the these headers:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:Spreadsheet"
       xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
       xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
       xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:Spreadsheet"
       xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

I had googling that for more than two days and i can´t find a solution for that, that it´s a very important file for the organization. Any idea about the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error trying to open it gives?

Comment: it open but in plain format, just like the post and in microsoft office it´s a regular spreadsheet. thanks!

Comment: the code it´s ok for microsoft office but in LibreOffice i can´t open it...i need a filter or something for LibreOffice to solve the problem..I can´t edit that code, it´s from a third party CRM.

Comment: My Libreoffice (Version: 5.1.6.2 Build ID: 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) **is** able opening such files. Choose File - Open. Select format "Microsoft Excel 2003 XML" from the Files of type list. Select the file name and click Open. See [Opening documents saved in other formats](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Opening_documents_saved_in_other_formats).